# Javascript make a div disappear on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Hello I'm trying to do a notification system on my website so that one can scroll to the right on a div to dismiss it. Here is my code:

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.fade {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #d15757;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.container1 {width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; }
.container2{width: 2000px; }
</style>
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
        <div>
            <div class="fade">
                Scroll down i will become invisible
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($('div.container1').scrollLeft()>0)
     {
        $('.fade').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.fade').fadeIn();
     }
 });
</script>
```

The only problem is that it doesn't work. Please feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Created a fiddle for you. Please have a look
https://jsfiddle.net/9z6ceczd/1/

Comment: Thanks @KoolShams ! That seems to work!